# Is there a way to get GHC profiling information exposed through a server socket?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

It is commonplace in the JVM world to use remote debugging capabilities of the JVM to get runntime tracing and profiling information: The JVM exposes a port to which a client can connect and be fed information from the runtime.

Is there a way to accomplish this in recent GHC?

Comment: I believe there is a GHC API for runtime information, look at the ekg package for a server that exposes this. I do not know if debug capabilities are exposed as well - the only experience debugging haskell code I have is using GHCi. Although I have to say I usually do not need elaborate debugging, Debug.Trace and referential transparency are sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, note that the JVM is a *virtual machine* interpreting Java bytecodes, whereas GHC compiles to native machine code.

Having said that, I'm not sure you can do much for *debugging*, but I think you can do something about *profiling*.

There's Threadscrope, of course, but it seems to only support post mortem analysis. I was *sure* I read somewhere that GHC's new event log system can be used for realtime analysis... but I can't find any details.

The best result I can find is the `ekg` package. It appears to use GHC's internal statistics gathering system and expose this over HTTP. Look it up on Hackage.

Comment: Well, I do not need debugging, it just happens that in the JVM the interface for retrieving the debugging and profiling are conflated (somehow, IIRC). Thanks, I am aware of ekg but did not investigate that feature.